# Use python to get realtime lidar data

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time, sensors, lidar

I tried this code for reference. I got this code from a question asked in stackoverflow.
I have used RPLIDAR A1M8 Sensor.

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      
from rplidar import RPLidar

def get_data():    
    lidar = RPLidar('COM5', baudrate=115200)
    for scan in lidar.iter_scans(max_buf_meas=500):    
        break    
        lidar.stop()    
    return scan

for i in range(1000000):    
    if(i%7==0):    
        x = np.radians([])   
        y = []    
    print(i)    
    current_data=get_data()    
    for point in current_data:    
        if point[0]==15:    
            x.append(point[2]*np.sin(point[1]))    
            y.append(point[2]*np.cos(point[1]))    
    plt.clf()    
    plt.scatter(x, y)    
    plt.pause(.1)    
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, it showed : could not conect to com port. 
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

apparently the lidar is connected to some different COM port than the port from this example. 
You need to change first parameter in this line:

```
lidar = RPLidar('COM5', baudrate=115200)
```

You can find out which port is it using in Windows Device Manager.